# How do I make this function fire at exactly 10% of the scrolled window/doc?

Tags: jquery

The below function fires function doSomething when it reaches 10% of the page, but as you continue to scroll, it keeps firing. How do i make it fire one at 10% and cease after that?

All the best,

Joey

```
  $(document).scroll(function(e){

      // grab the scroll amount and the window height
      var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
      var documentHeight = $(document).height();

      // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
      var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

      if(scrollPercent = 10) {
          // run a function called doSomething
          doSomething();
      }

      function doSomething() { 
            $(".fill").append('<img src="img/arrow-down.png"/>');

          // do something when a user gets 10% of the way down my page
      }

  });
```

Comment: is that a typo? It should be `if(scrollPercent === 10 )`, otherwise you're just assigning to the variable `scrollPercent`

Comment: use Math.round(), and mark somehow that you already fired the function before it will not reach 11% or 9%

Comment: tried scrollPercent === 10 with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser the scroll event can fire a LOT.  Better to use a timer.

Try the following:

```
var  didScroll = false;
var doneAction = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
      didScroll = false;

      // grab the scroll amount and the window height
      var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
      var documentHeight = $(document).height();

      // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
      var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

      if(scrollPercent >= 10 && !doneAction) {
          alert('You just scrolled to 10 percent.'); // or whatever action you want to perform
          doneaction = true;
      }
    }
}, 250);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice this works (except you made a typo and for to capitalize doneAction.) Also, what does the 250 represent? Thanks @Tims

Comment: @JoeIsaacson 250ms is the interval at which the callback function will fire.

Comment: exactly.  this script is checking every 250ms to see if the window was scrolled.